# C# Reading and Writing File over Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, byte, file-writing

I am have a pretty weird issue right now with how i'm sending my data over sockets. My read buffer is getting all the data i'm sending through the socket, but for some reason the File.Write or File.WriteAsync methods i'm calling are not writing all the bytes, or just stopping(I think that's the issue) OR it could be something wrong with the sockets and how they're being read and written too.

So here is a snippet of my code, keep in mind, both of these are on the same file but are different threads.

```
   byte[] Buffer = new Byte[1024];
   int bytesRead;
   while((bytesRead = ReceiverSocket.Receive(Buffer)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                //myDownload.Write(Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                myDownload.WriteAsync(Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
```

The code above is my receive function for my download client. Keep in mind i'm getting the same results regardless of what write method I use.

And I am simply using this:

```
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToSend);
    serverSocket.SendFile(fileToSend);
```

I send a file with filesize: 10560 and actually retrieve all the bytes over the receive loop, yet when I check my file after i'm done it only receives a portion like so:

TotalBytesRead

1024

2048

3072
...

...8192

9216

10240

10560

Which means it reads all the data, though in my program, it's still stuck inside the loop and when i close it to check the filesize, it's size is 8192, so it seems to me it didn't read the next 3 socket streams.

I'm at a loss for this, is there anything i'm doing wrong? Could this be a threading issue i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, I was locking on my

```
    while((bytesRead = ReceiverSocket.Receive(Buffer)) > 0)
```

due to the socket always waiting on a receive, so the SendFile wouldn't necessarily send 0, so it was always stuck in the while loop, but one I closed the while, it finished writing to file.